# What is the python time.sleep() delay equivalent for node.js and javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, timedelay

In python, it is easy to create a time delay with `time.sleep()`. Is there any equivalent for node.js? I cannot find it. I suspect it may be due to asynchronous nature of node.js. Hoping someone on StackOverflow can provide an easy solution like `time.sleep()` in node.js or javascript.

Comment: setTimeout loop ..

Comment: It's not exactly an apples to apples comparison, sleeping in python vs js so it's difficult to answer. Perhaps you could share your actual problem?

Comment: Probably approaching problem all wrong and should be using promises